# How to overloading constructors if using multiple classes in one file

Tags: java

When I try to compile this, it says "cannot find symbol constructor Armor(int,int,int,java.lang.String)". However, when I change Armor(blunt, pierce, cut, name) to Armor(), it works perfectly fine. Am I not allowed to overload constructors if I'm using multiple classes in a single file (here I have class resistance and class Armor in one file). It is absolutely necessary for me to put them in the same file, because I am practicing this for a competition where you cannot submit more than 1 file.

```
public class resistance
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int blunt=4;
        int pierce=2;
        int cut=7;
        String name="Helmet";
        Armor item = new Armor(blunt, pierce, cut, name);
    }
}

class Armor
{
int blunt;
int pierce;
int cut;
String name;

void Armor()
{
    blunt=0;
    pierce=0;
    cut=0;
    name="";
}

void Armor(int a, int b, int c, String d)
{
    blunt=a;
    pierce=b;
    cut=c;
    name=d;
}
}
```

Comment: It's generally accepted to use the one class per file setup in Java.  It will help you greatly in clarity and future debugging to stick with this idiom.

Answer (score 6):

`void Armor(...)` is a method with the same name as the class.
`Armor(...)` is a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "overload" it, you have to define explicitely this constructor:

```
public Armor(int a,int b,int c,String d){
}
```

in your Armor class. If you declare a method with a return type, like `void`, then it is not a constructor anymore, but a method.

Answer (score 1):

These are not constructors. They have a return type, so they are methods. Get rid of `void`.

If you are using an IDE, pay attention to the warnings it gives you. For example eclipse tells you "This method has a constructor name", which immediately helps you realize the mistake.